# What does the Argument "type" in VAR() - function do?

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, vector-autoregression

Right now I am working with vector autoregressive models in order to make 3 months forecasts for a commodity good (sawlogs) y. I have several time-series of "follow-up-products" of sawlogs that should work as "predictors" for saw-log prices from a logical point of view. 
I encountered within the VAR-function from package "vars" (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vars.pdf), that one attribute called "type" has the following expressions: "const", "both", "trend", "none". I really don't know what this means from a statistical point of view.

Since neither the package-description nor other literature I've screened so far can give me an answer I actually understand I'd like to ask you guys the following:

How should I interpret/understand and use the argument "type" in R's VAR() Function?

What do those 4 different arguments really mean? "both", "none", "trend", "constant"?
Could anyone explain this in a simple way and probably provide an example as well?

Does this mean that I can directly use non-stationary time series for my VAR-model since I can consider trend/season afterwards by setting the "type-argument" to both, or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`constant` means there is an intercept included in each equation in the model. `trend` means there is a linear time trend included. `both` means both of them are included. `none` means neither of them is included.

Type `?VAR` in `R` to get an explanation. There you will find the algebraic form of the model provided. Pay attention to the *CD_t* term. You may also see the [vignette](ftp://ftp.math.ethz.ch/sfs/CRAN/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf) for the `vars` package, perhaps it could help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard. I read the vignette and didn't really get smarter afterwards. Sometimes it is stated that the data has to be stationary BEFORE usig a VAR model, then I ask myself how there even could be a trend?

Does this "type"argument imply that you can directly use non-stationary data within a VARestimateion and then set "type" to "both" in order to consider trend and season?

Comment: If the non-stationarity is caused by a deterministic time trend (for example, a linear time trend), it can be treated by including a time trend regressor in the VAR model (option `type="trend"`). If, on the other hand, non-stationarity is due to the process being integrated (e.g. I(1) process), this cannot be cured in such a simple way. By the way, `both` is **not** about seasonal component. There is another option for that – it has a name `season`.